# Android ViewPager update list adapter from a different tabbed fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a View pager Fragment called **SalesPartsFragmentHolder** which has two child tabbed fragments

```
 SalesPartsFragment

 SelectedSalesPartsFragment
```

Both of these contains Lists with an adapter.  What I want to happen is when an item is clicked on **SalesPartsFragment**, it is added to **SelectedSalesPartsFragment**. So, when a user moves to the other tab it is showing.  I have tried

```
mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

but this is too slow, if it is possible to tell the list adapter in SelectedSalesPartsFragment or to get mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); to run on the click of a list item from within SalesPartsFragment would be great.  Any ideas?/ thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create interface in SalesPartsFragment. Example

```
class SalesPartsFragment extends Fragment{
...
public interface onSalesPartsFragmentListener{
   public void onItemClick()
}
private onSalesPartsFragmentListener mListener;
...
@Ovveride
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
   mListener = (onSalesPartsFragmentListener)activity;
}
...
void onItemClick(){
   mListener.onItemClick();
}
```

Activity must implements onSalesPartsFragmentListener and notify SelectedSalesPartsFragment when SelectedSalesFragment was clicked.

```
class MainActivity extends Activity implements onSalesPartsFragmentListener{
...
public void onItemClick(){
   selectedSalesPartsFragment.update()
}
```

In SelectedSalesPartsFragment create method update() and call notifyDataSetChanged();